# Can I set an ECMAScript 6 Javascript Map() Object as a Lightning Component Attribute?

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, lightning-apps, aura-attribute, framework

I have a scenario where I am building a Javascript Map() object in my client controller helper of a Lightning component. Ideally, I would like to use this map for client-side filtering in a component. Each key value pair would contain the filter value as the key and the record to be returned as the value.

I am initially building this map object in the callback of the init function when I have successfully retrieve Account records from the server. This code is below:

```
({
    // Fetch the accounts from the Apex controller
    getAccountList: function(component) {
        var action = component.get('c.getAccounts');

        // Set up the callback
        var self = this;
        action.setCallback(this, function(actionResult) {
            component.set('v.accounts', actionResult.getReturnValue());
            this.buildJSONLookup(component);
        });
        $A.enqueueAction(action);
    },

    buildJSONLookup: function(component) {
        var recordList = component.get('v.accounts');
        var mAccounts = new Map();
        recordList.forEach(function(account) {
            if(mAccounts.has(account.CreatedDate)) {
                mAccounts.get(account.CreatedDate).push(account);   
            } else {
                mAccounts.set(account.CreatedDate, [account]);
            }
        });
        component.set('v.mAccounts', mAccounts);
        console.log(component.get('v.mAccounts'));
    }
})
```

At the end, I am trying to set the new Javascript Map() object to the attribute "Map" type in the component markup. However, when I try to log that component attribute to the console after the value has been set, it simply returns an empty object.

I am wondering if it is possible to set this ECMAScript 6 Javascript map to a Lightning component attribute with the "Map" type? If not, I wanted to see if there were any work arounds? I preferably want to use some kind of lookup function that would prevent looping through the entire list of records each time filtering happens.

Comment: Can you add more code here .Specially your component mark up and how you have declared attributes .

Comment: Yes, it is possible to use ECMAScript 6 JS maps and set it in a lightning component attribute with the Map type.
The only concerns which I have heard sometimes is passing these attributes to a dynamically created component(I haven't faced such issues yet.)